# AWS Lambda logging into CloudWatch group logs events twice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

for mobile app dev purposes, we introduced AWS Lambda capable of logging into predefined CloudWatch logGroup and logStream

Simplified Node.js Lambda:

```js
export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent): Promise<{ headers: { "content-type": string }; body: string; statusCode: number }> => {
  const logs = new CloudWatchLogs();
  const events: PutLogEventsRequest = JSON.parse(event.body!);
  await logs.putLogEvents(events, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
        result = data;

    }).promise();
  return {statusCode: 200, headers: {"content-type": "plain/text"}, body: "OK"};
}
```

This Lambda is configured as an ApiGateway route

**The 1st after Lambda deploy with the http body**

```json
{
   "logEvents": [ 
      { 
         "message": "Something happened 001",
         "timestamp": 1695215849616
      }
   ],
   "logGroupName": "the-log-group",
   "logStreamName": "the-log-stream"
}
```

Logs only one event into the-log-group/the-log-stream CloudWatch, which is correct:

```
Something happened 001
```

**2nd call with body**

```json
{
   "logEvents": [ 
      { 
         "message": "Something happened 002",
         "timestamp": 1695215849616
      }
   ],
   "logGroupName": "the-log-group",
   "logStreamName": "the-log-stream"
}
```

results into (final state of the logstream):

```
Something happened 001
Something happened 001
Something happened 002
Something happened 002
```

**3rd call with body**

```json
{
   "logEvents": [ 
      { 
         "message": "Something happened 003",
         "timestamp": 1695215849618
      }
   ],
   "logGroupName": "the-log-group",
   "logStreamName": "the-log-stream"
}
```

results into (final state of the logstream):

```
Something happened 001
Something happened 001
Something happened 002
Something happened 002
Something happened 003
Something happened 003
```

I do not have a clue why is it behaving this way. Could someone guide me to the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: are the request IDs same?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur its always the new request (hence new request ID I guess) . Interesting you are asking, why this should play any role?

Comment: it seems the problem is on your ApiGateway, not lambda itself